# Cannot run emulator in a container on a windows host

Tags: android, docker, android-emulator, emulation, docker-for-windows

I want to run an emulator in a docker container, so i searched for it and found
many docker-android-emulator images on the internet but most of them have written that this docker image won't run on a Windows host.

This is because the emulator uses KVM on Linux so we need to have access to the host's KVM. In the Linux kernel, Nested virtualization is possible so the container which will be running in a Linux host can run the emulator.

But the windows host doesn't have nested virtualization so the container can't use the host's KVM, this way it can't be run on a Windows host.

But I have seen some people run in window's host too, can anybody tell me how can I achieve this?